# Dealing with RESTful service that returns different DTOs in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto

I'm working on a service right now where there is a method that makes a call to another endpoint. This downstream call returns three different "flavors" of JSon objects. Right now the way I'm dealing with this is by having a dto class like this (just to be clear, only ONE of these DtoX classes is sent in a request; two will always be null):

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentDto {
    private String data;
    private DtoA A;
    private DtoB B;
    private DtoC C;
}
```

Each of these three Dtos contain their own subfields. They are quite different from one another. I am able to deal with all of these because of the annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` however someone on my team would prefer it if we could find a cleaner way that is more clear. They would rather have an interface or an abstract class like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentDto {
    private String data;
}
```

and extend it by three different classes like:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DtoFlavorA extends ParentDto {
    private ArrayList<String> strings; //add all specific fields here
}
```

I can't see how this can be done because Spring needs to know exactly what fields will be present to fill them in for us. It seems to me that I would have to parse the incoming JSon string myself, which really defeats the purpose of having a Dto in the first place.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance. It shows you how to do it. Basically you need to define the children objects as part of the parent object using annotations and that will add help the json serialiser to do it automatically

Comment: what is the possibility here that both Dto A and Dto B will be preseo in response or it would be one flavour always?

Comment: @ruba that link was informative and interesting, but it doesn't help me because I have no control over the data that is incoming and am unable to add a `type` field to the json.

Comment: @code_mechanic virtually a 0% chance, and if it did happen, it wouldn't be my fault.

Comment: You mean by 0 percent that it would be one flavour always ?

Comment: All three flavors of DTO will be sent from time to time, and I can be reasonably sure that only one will be sent at a time. @code_mechanic

Comment: Then can you elaborate why you can't apply examples given in that article?

Comment: @code_mechanic because in order for those solutions to work, the incoming json request bodies need to have a `type` field that specifies the type of object it is. I have no control over how requests come in so that won't work. At this point I'm leaning towards just leaving it like I originally had it.

Comment: yeah if you have more custom requirements then it is better to leave it as it is, I often find its not worth investing time considering the structure changes so often.

Comment: @Astrum check the article for `2.2. Per-Class Annotations`. That way you don't need to pass a type in request body